# Compare 2 records and update a new field with YES or NO in POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, for-loop, compare

i have a requirement for which we need 'for_loop' statements in POSTGRESQL,
Can anyone help with CODE?

table name nex_outages has fields:

- serial_number
- outage_type
- outage_start_date
- last_modified_date
- outage_event_name.

We have to sort descending on: serial_number,outage_type and outage_start_date. Then compare 1st row of serial_number with 2nd row serial_number.

If both matches then compare 1st row outage_type with 2nd row outage_type and if both matches then check the difference between 1st row outage_start_date with 2nd row outage_start_date, if the difference is more than 61 days then set is_duplicate field (new field) = 'NO' for the 1st row and if the difference of outage_start_date is less than or equal to 61 days then compare 1st row last_modified_date with 2nd row last_modified_date and which last_modified_date is recent set is_duplicate = 'NO'

If 2nd row last_modified_date is recent then assign NO to 2nd row and next above comparison must happen between 1st row and 3rd row and loop.

currently my table has 50,000 records. Looking for "FOR_LOOP" query to achieve this

Sample data

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| outage_type           | outage_event_name | outage_start_date     | serial_number | last_modified_date    | created_date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Major Inspection      | 83230             | 11/1/2033 0:00        | SY0073277     | 12/21/2017 8:31       | 12/21/2017 8:31   |
| Major Inspection      | 54578             | 11/1/2024 0:00        | SY0073277     | 12/23/2016 8:31       | 12/23/2016 8:31   |
| Major Inspection (MI) | 83231             | 10/30/2033 0:00       | SY0073277     | 4/12/2019 0:39        | 12/21/2017 8:31   |
| Major Inspection (MI) | 115317            | 11/1/2024 0:00        | SY0073277     | 11/8/2018 6:46        | 3/5/2018 14:58    |
| Major Inspection (MI) | 54579             | 2/3/2024 0:00         | SY0073277     | 4/11/2019 23:58       | 12/23/2016 8:31   |
| Minor Inspection      | 54576             | 12/27/2029 0:00       | SY0073277     | 12/23/2016 8:31       | 12/23/2016 8:31   |
| Minor Inspection      | 54577             | 12/26/2029 0:00       | SY0073277     | 4/12/2019 1:24        | 12/23/2016 8:31   |
| Minor Inspection      | 83229             | 11/26/2028 0:00       | SY0073277     | 4/12/2019 0:36        | 12/21/2017 8:31   |
| Minor Inspection      | 83228             | 11/21/2028 0:00       | SY0073277     | 12/21/2017 8:31       | 12/21/2017 8:31   |
| Minor Inspection      | 54575             | 4/24/2019 0:00        | SY0073277     | 5/25/2019 0:31        | 12/23/2016 8:31   |
| Minor Inspection      | 86703             | 4/20/2019 0:00        | SY0073277     | 4/12/2019 0:17        | 1/10/2018 19:46   |
| Minor Inspection      | 54574             | 4/20/2019 0:00        | SY0073277     | 1/10/2018 16:16       | 12/23/2016 8:31   |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION duplicates() 
RETURNS VOID 
AS $$
DECLARE 
cur cursor for 
Select
outage_type
, outage_event_name
, outage_start_date
, serial_number
, last_modified_date
, created_date
, MIN(OUTAGE_START_DATE) OVER (partition by OUTAGE_TYPE,SERIAL_NUMBER ORDER BY OUTAGE_START_DATE desc 
ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
as nextrecord
, lead(OUTAGE_START_DATE) OVER(partition by OUTAGE_TYPE,SERIAL_NUMBER ORDER BY OUTAGE_START_DATE 
desc) osd_lead
, lead(last_modified_date) OVER(partition by OUTAGE_TYPE,SERIAL_NUMBER ORDER BY OUTAGE_START_DATE 
desc) lmd_lead
, lag(OUTAGE_START_DATE) OVER(partition by OUTAGE_TYPE,SERIAL_NUMBER ORDER BY OUTAGE_START_DATE desc) 
 osd_lag
, lag(last_modified_date) OVER(partition by OUTAGE_TYPE,SERIAL_NUMBER ORDER BY OUTAGE_START_DATE 
 desc) lmd_lag
 , lead(outage_type) OVER(partition by OUTAGE_TYPE,SERIAL_NUMBER ORDER BY OUTAGE_START_DATE desc) 
 otg_typ
 , 'NO' as is_duplicate
 FROM sot_steam_da.nex_outages_src
 where serial_number = 'SY0073277'
 and outage_type = 'Minor Inspection'
 order by outage_start_date desc,last_modified_date desc,outage_type desc;

 cur_row sot_steam_da.nex_outages_src%rowtype;

 BEGIN
FOR cur_row in cur 

LOOP
    Update sot_steam_da.nex_outages_src 
    set is_duplicate = if (outage_start_date::date - osd_lead::date) <= 61 and outage_type = otg_typ THEN
                             'No';
                         elseif (last_modified_date <= lmd_lead) then 'Yes';
                         else 'No';
                              end if;
                               
    
END LOOP;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

this code is not properly coded for whole requirement and above code is throwing syntax error after 1st IF statement and we are trying 1st for few records to get accurate output with where condition in above code..

Comment: You don't have a question, you haven't described what your problem is. Your question is a huge mess of fields and rules. You don't have sample data that someone could actually use if the are not deterred by all the other things...

Comment: i need code for my requirement so i had written my entire requirement for better understanding with field names and i updated sample data screenshot and some data as well now, expected output in screen shot @JamesZ

Answer (score 0):

OK, you seem to have made reasonable progress with putting together your function. On the UPDATE statement (though I'm not expert on PostgreSQL), I believe your syntax is indeed incorrect. The IF clause is not valid in the context of the UPDATE/SET. You need to use a CASE statement instead, something like below.  Hopefully this helps you get further down the path.

```
UPDATE sot_steam_da.nex_outages_src 
   SET is_duplicate = CASE WHEN (outage_start_date::date - osd_lead::date) <= 61 
                            AND outage_type = otg_typ 
                           THEN 'No'
                           WHEN (last_modified_date <= lmd_lead) 
                               THEN 'Yes'
                           ELSE     
                               'No'
                      END;
```